# Error during FORM auth in Tomcat

Tags: java, authentication, tomcat

I want to make authentication controled by Tomcat. To test it I created to simple pages, login page and loginError page. 
Authentication seemed to work. When I enter wrong login or password I see loginError page. But when I enter correct login and password I see:

```
type Status report

message Access to the requested resource has been denied

description Access to the specified resource (Access to the requested resource has been denied) has been forbidden.
```

Here is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <url-pattern>/protected.jsp</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>*</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
    </security-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/loginError.jsp</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Here is my tomcat-users.xml

```
<tomcat-users>

  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
    <role rolename="admin"/>
    <role rolename="manager"/>
    <user password="tomcat" roles="tomcat,manager,admin" username="tomcat"/>
    <user password="proger" roles="tomcat" username="proger"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

My login.jsp looks like:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <form id="loginForm" method="post" action="j_security_check">
            <p>
                Username: <input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username" />
                <br/>
                Password: <input type="password" name="j_password" id="j_password" />
                <br/>
                <button type="submit">login</button>
            </p>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

I deploy it I use NetBeans 6.9.1. I use Tomcat 6.0.29.
What can be wrong?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try with an explicit role name like `tomcat` instead of wildcard `*`. I recall some issues regarding this, but I'd be surprised if that isn't fixed in the most recent Tomcat 6 which you have there.

Comment: It isn't fixed. Thank you for your advice. It helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using

```
   <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
```

requires that you also define 'valid' roles

```
<security-role>
      <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
     <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

If the user enters a valid name/pass, but is only in role 'dimwit', they'll get access denied